# a typo about free groups in Dummit's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, free-groups, group-presentation

I am not sure that if there is a typo in Dummit's Abstract Algebra on page219 : Let $S=G$ and the map $\pi:F(S)\to G$ is the homomorphism extending the identity map of $S$ . the first paragragh writes " $R_0\leq\ker\pi$ " where $R_0$ is the set of words $g_ig_jg_k^{-1}$ , these $g$ are elements in the finite group $G$ satisfying $g_ig_j=_Gg_k$ .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPJTS.png)

It is clear that $R_0\subseteq\ker\pi$ , but how to show that $R_0\leq\ker\pi$ ? If so, we can also obtain $R_0\leq F(S)$ by $\ker\pi\leq F(S)$ , hence $R_0$ is also a free group since every subgroup of a free group is free. But I think " $R_0$ is the set of words $g_ig_jg_k^{-1}$ " restricts the length of each word in $R_0$ to be $\leq3$ , and this is a contradiction with that $R_0$ is free.

Comment: Yes they are just saying that $R_0$ is a subset of ker $\pi$.  If they use $\leq$ exclusively to say 'subgroup' then it is a typo.

Comment: Yes, in this book $\leq$ is just to show "subgroup" and $\subseteq$ to show "subset", thanks!

Comment: By the way, the subgroup $R$, generated by $R_0$ and its inverses is already a normal subgroup, so you do not need take normal closure.  See for example Lemma 3.5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/0908.3765.pdf.  The notation there writes $s_g$ as the element of $S$ corresponding to $g\in G$.  Note the theorem tells you that any $u\in F(S)$ equals something in $R$ multiplied by $s_{\pi u}$.  Thus if $u\in$ker $\pi$, then $u$ equals something in $R$, multiplied by $s_e$.  But $s_e=s_es_e{s_e}^{-1}\in R_0$.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text

Comment: @tkf Thanks, I find it a typo in the author's errata: https://site.uvm.edu/ddummit/files/2021/04/errata_3rd_edition_4_19_2021.pdf